# Can anyone explain this snippet of Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain the following code?  Forget the sine and cosine parts.  Is it trying to build a space for the object?

```
objectsInScene = new Array();

for (var i=space; i<180; i+=space) {

  for (var angle=0; angle<360; angle+=space) {

    var object = {};

    var x = Math.sin(radian*i)*radius;
    object.x = Math.cos(angle*radian)*x;
    object.y = Math.cos(radian*i)*radius;
    object.z = Math.sin(angle*radian)*x;
    objectsInScene.push(object);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's filling `objectsInScene` with a **sphere** of points (not a hemisphere), spaced `space` degrees apart.   The diameter is 2 times `radius`.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not much mistaken it's arranging objects in a <strike>hemi</strike>spherical shape.

`objectsInScene` is an array of all these objects.